# facebook share dialog shows can't load url

Tags: javascript, php, facebook

i am trying share dialog. In documentation, i ran the example and it worked. But when i ran on my localhost, the dialog popped up but it says "can't load url,The domain of this URL isn't......."
Below is my code. It's right after the body tag.

```
<script>

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId            : '1538657022815637',
      autoLogAppEvents : true,
      xfbml            : true,
      version          : 'v2.9'
    });
    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
  };



(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8&appId=1538657022815637";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>



 <div id="shareBtn" class="btn btn-success clearfix">Share</div>

<script>
document.getElementById('shareBtn').onclick = function() {
  FB.ui({
    method: 'share',
    display: 'popup',
    href: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',
  }, function(response){});
}
</script>
```

Comment: Is `localhost` configured as one of the valid domains for your app?

Comment: my root localhost is "http://localhost:81/cars", i tried putting this in 'app domain' field in facebook app settings, but it said "top level domain is not allowed"

Comment: after i added plateform and then in setting i changed site url to "http://localhost:81/" and was able to put 'localhost' in 'app domain field' and now the dialog is showing. Thanks for your suggestion. Another question do u know what 'url redirection' is in share dialog.

Comment: That's the URL you want the user to go to after they complete the share dialog. You could track completion of the process there, or close the popup.